# what is the difference between $\log_ax^2$ and $2\log_ax$

Tags: calculus, inequality

when are we allowed to make the use of the formular $\log_ab^c=c\log_ab$

for example solving the logarithmic inequality

$\log _2(-t)+\log_2(t)^2<3$

is solveable if $t <0$
but

$\log _2(-t)+2\log_2(t)<3$

is **not**,
which is logically the same thing

Comment: You have to be careful where you place your brackets. $\log_a(b^c) = c\log_a(b)$, but $\log_a(b)^c \neq c\log_a(b)$.

Comment: $\log_a b^c =c\log_a b$ if $a,b>0$, but definitely not when $b<0$. In particular, $\log_2(-t)$ being defined means $t<0$, so $\log_2 t$ is not defined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i get it,but would $t<0$ work if we stick with the first form,and Marc would the inequality be solveable if we consider the parenthesis $\log_a(b)^c$ and not $\log_a(b^c)$

Comment: this is the original problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756230/solve-a-system-of-inequalities

Comment: Marc's problem is that $f(a)^b$ is usually shorthand for $(f(a))^b$, and then $\log_a(b)^c\neq \log_a(b^c)$. I assumed that was writing $\log_a(b)^c$ was a notation mistake on your part, intending $\log_a(b^c)$ @Jonas12